# Laravel Echo not listening

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a real-time post using Laravel with ReactJS and Pusher. I have been able to create pusher events and i could see the events showing on the pusher site. However, Laravel echo does not listen to the event whenever it is created and i cannot figure out why or how to make it to listen.

**App\Events\PostCreated**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class PostCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $post;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        //
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('new-post'),
            new PrivateChannel('App.User.' . $this->post->user->id),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith() {
        return [
            'post' => array_merge($this->post->toArray(), [
                'user' => $this->post->user,
            ]),
            'user' => $this->user,
        ];
    }
}
```

**broadcasting.php**

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => getenv('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => getenv('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => getenv('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => getenv('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],
```

**.env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

PUSHER_APP_ID=757605
PUSHER_APP_KEY=4100ca8b118192fd01b2
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=41f43d23204a3c7ae2a7
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap1
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

//const client = require('pusher-js');

//import 'pusher-js/node';

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '4100ca8b118192fd01b2',
    cluster: 'ap1',
    encrypted: true
});
```

**channels.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('new-post', function ($user) {
    return Auth::check();
});
```

**PostController**

```
public function create(Request $request, Post $post) {
        $data = [];
        $video_data = [];
        if ($request->get('file')) {
            foreach ($request->get('file') as $file) {
                $name = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($file, 0, strpos($file, ';')))[1])[1];
                $upload = Uploader::upload($file, array('public_id' => $name));
                array_push($data, $upload['secure_url']);
            }
        }
        if ($request->get('video')) {
            foreach ($request->get('video') as $file) {
                $name = md5(uniqid() . '.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($file, 0, strpos($file, ';')))[1]))[1];
                $upload = Uploader::upload($file, array('public_id' => $name, 'resource_type' => 'video'));
                array_push($video_data, $upload['secure_url']);
            }
        }
        $image = !empty($data) ? json_encode($data) : null;
        $video = !empty($video_data) ? json_encode($video_data) : null;
        $body = $this->test_data($request->body);
        // create post
        $createdPost = $request->user()->posts()->create([
            'body' => $body,
            'image' => $image,
            'video' => $video
        ]);
        // broadcast
        broadcast(new PostCreated($createdPost, $request->user()))->toOthers();
        // return the response
        return response()->json($post->with('user')->find($createdPost->id));
    }
```

**app.blade.php (App Layout)**

```
<script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
            'user' => [
                'id' => Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id : null,
                'following' => Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->following()->pluck('users.id') : null
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
    </script>
```

**ReactJS (Frontend)**

```
componentDidMount() {
        Echo.private('new-post').listen('PostCreated', (e) => {
            if (window.Laravel.user.following.includes(e.post.user_id)) {
                this.setState({ posts: [e.post, ...this.state.posts] });
            }
        });
        // this.interval = setInterval(()=>this.getPosts(), 10000);
    }
```

I expect the followers of the user that created a new post to see the post instantly without reloading the page but instead, nothing happens.

The event is created but it is not listened to. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out and noticed that i have to keep running the following command:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Comment: I have the same problem with my Plesk server running my Laravel-Vue chat application on it and could not solve my issue with this command. I even explicity open Laravel Echo port 6001 on server firewall settings but no luck. There are lots of examples that were not resolved on Stackoverflow too. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

try to set `broadcastAs` in your event class and explicitly set the broadcast name in reactjs part.

**App\Events\PostCreated**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

class PostCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    // other code
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'PostCreated';
    }
}
```

**ReactJS (Frontend)**

```
componentDidMount() {
        Echo.private('new-post').listen('.PostCreated', (e) => {
            if (window.Laravel.user.following.includes(e.post.user_id)) {
                this.setState({ posts: [e.post, ...this.state.posts] });
            }
        });
        // this.interval = setInterval(()=>this.getPosts(), 10000);
    }
```

notice that I use `.PostCreated` ( and not **PostCreated**). By, default, laravel has convention on the broadcast name. I prefer explicit programming style so I usually set `broadcastAs` for all my events.

Comment: the docs are very unclear on this IMO - this solved my issue +1